# Backing a public property with a private property?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at some code and found this kind of pattern:

```
private string text { get; set; }
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return text;
    }
    set
    {
        text= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
    }
}
```

I normally just back my public properties with private fields.

Is there any reason a property should be backed by a private property like this? My instinct is to say that it shouldn't, and this should be backed by a field instead, is that right? Any technical reasons I can use to back this up?

Comment: There's no reason this wouldn't work.  Have you encountered an actual problem with this?

Comment: There's no technical limitation here, although I think best practice would dictate using a field in this case, always.

Comment: Well, I don't see a good reason for doing this, but technically there's no reason why it shouldn't work. There may be more overhead involved, however if you do it (one would have to compare the IL outputs), and that's why I'd go the classic way of using a variable instead of another property. Could also be the optimizer turns the private generic property into a field anyway?

Comment: It seems like there's a lot of opinion behind this one.  As for a *technical* reason, no there is no technical reason why this can't be done.  Whether or not one *should* do it is really going to depend on what's being implemented.  It's possible that the class is complex enough that private members can benefit from abstraction behind properties.  And a public property exposing the state of the class may want to make use of that abstraction.  The benefits of this approach are really on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I think in most cases it should be fine to do it either way. Having it as a property makes it slightly more flexible, but the instances where it would actually make a difference are few enough that you shouldn't need to worry about which you use.

Answer (score 1):

Typical case is when you have a *raw data* (data as it is without any transformation) and the *same data*, but friendly represented:

```
  private String m_RawText;

  // Text as it's obtained from, say, database 
  private string rawText { 
    get {
      if (null == m_RawText)
        m_RawText = ReadValueFromDataBase();

      return m_RawText;
    } 
    set {
      if (m_RawText != value) {
        UpdateValueInDataBase(value);

        m_RawText = value;
      }
    }  
  }

  // Friendly encoded text, for say UI
  public string Text {
    get {
      return EncondeText(rawTex);
    }
    set {
      rawText = DecodeText(value);

      RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
   }
 }  

 // Here we want rawText
 public void PerformSomething() {
   String text = rawText; // we want raw text...
   ...
 } 

 // And here we prefer Text
 public override String ToString() {
   return String.Fromat("Text = {0} ", Text, ...)
 }
```

Comment: This STILL does not answer the OP's question, post edit.  The exact same raw data storage can be accomplished with a field or property.

Comment: I think the example is a little confusing (at least to me), but I agree with the overall spirit of the answer here.  In even moderately complex scenarios, a class can easily have a private member which is abstracted behind a property for any variety of reasons.  Some common logic to be invoked when reading or writing that member, even if it's only ever invoked privately.  When exposing the state of the object, the public property may also want to take advantage of that same common logic, and would therefore use the private property as its backing data instead of the raw field.